# fetching non-ascii ftp filename with openurl

Tags: python, ftp, fetch, ftplib, openurl

I'm trying to fetch a file from ftp that has Cyrillic characters:

```
url = 'ftp://user:pass@host/'
file_path = 'non-ASCII symbols.xlsx'

try:
    r = urlopen(url_str + quote_plus(file_path))
```

> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 194, in putline
>   self.sock.sendall(line.encode(self.encoding)) UnicodeEncodeError:
>   'latin-1' codec can't encode characters...

Default encoding in ftplib.py is Latin-1. Is there a way to change ftplib encoding at urlopen or convert my url to the necessary encoding?

Comment: Try Google on "URL encoded string".

Comment: i used quote_plus(file_path) as you see.

Comment: It looks as if the routine can only handle "latin-1" characters... So it's not a problem of `openurl()`, but a problem of `quote_plus()`-